# Why does it skip the 'if' statements in my python 3.x code for a simple RockPaperScissors?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from random import randint
print('''Choose one:1.Rock
    2.Paper
    3.Scissors
    ''')
userChoice = input(Choose one:1.Rock, 2.Paper, 3.Scissors.)

computerChoice=randint(1,3)

if userChoice==1 :

    print("your choice is Rock.", end='')

    if computerChoice==2 :
        print("but computer chose Paper. XD. You lose!")
    elif computerChoice==1 :
        print("Here. Take another one. Hope you make some fire!(If you didn't get it, it's a draw!)")
    else :
        ("You're better than a machine (for now). You win! XO")

elif userChoice==2:
    print("your choice is: Paper.", end ='')
    if computerChoice==2:
        print("and please stop mimicking the system. It's a Draw.")
    elif computerChoice==1:
        print(" Victorious! Poor system chose a Rock apparently.")
    else :
        ("Hehe! my scissors have torn your paper. XD")

elif userChoice==3:

    print("your choice is:Scissors.", end='')
    if(computerChoice == 2):
        print("You've cut some virtual paper eventually. You did it! yay!")
    elif(computerChoice == 1):
        print("Wrong choice. Your scissors are blunted by y rock Loser!")
    else :
        ("Apparently you're mocking the computer :(. Why did you both choose the same")     
else :
    print("I didn't give you any such choice.")
```

Comment: input returns a string in python 3 you need to convert to integer

Comment: Input always returns a string. Try to do `int(input( ... ))`. And also, please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful. :D